# how to validate joi sub-schema in best way

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

Is it possible to validate `joi` schema without getting casting error? i.e. I have **N** fields but I want to validate **1** field only.

I have tried **2** ways, as below:

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const _ = require('lodash');
const testSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().trim().min(5).max(25).required(),
    allowed: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(1).default(0)
});

// works smoothly; no error
// const {error, value} = Joi.validate({name :"abc", allowed: 1}, testSchema);

// (Way 1) --> Error: "value" must be a number
// const {error, value} = Joi.validate({name :"abc", allowed: 1}, Joi.reach(testSchema, 'allowed'));

// (Way 2) --> Error: "value" must be a number
const {error, value} = Joi.validate({name :"abc", allowed: 1}, _.find(testSchema._inner.children, {key: 'allowed'}).schema);

console.log(error);
```

P.S. I know the **3rd** approach to compose final schema from smaller schema(s) but I don't want to go for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of key value object just pass the value of the key, like:

```
Joi.validate(1, Joi.reach(testSchema, 'allowed'));
```